# how to merge tables and sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with some specific data:

```
users:
+----+------------+
| id |  username  |
+----+------------+
| 1  |    rob     |
| 2  |    john    |
| 3  |    jane    | <--- jane never has donated
+----+------------+

donations:
+--------------------+------------+
|   uid   |  amount  |   date     |
+---------+----------+------------+
|    1    |    20    | 2013-10-10 | 
|    2    |    5     | 2013-10-03 | 
|    2    |    50    | 2013-09-25 |
|    2    |    5     | 2013-10-01 |
+---------+----------+------------+


Result I want:
+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|    id   |   username  | amount  |   monthly   | <- sum of donations this month
+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|    1    |     rob     |   20    |      1      |
|    2    |     john    |   60    |      3      |
|    3    |     jane    |   0     |      0      | <- jane added
+---------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT t1.*, sum(t2.amount) amount, count(*) as monthly
FROM users t1
inner join donations t2
  on t2.uid = t1.id
group by t1.username
```

EDIT: forgot to add jane, he never has donated.

How I can do this?

Comment: And what doesn't work with that solution?

Comment: What constitutes a month?  Same month (october) or past 30 days?  I don't see how John has 3.

Comment: @bluefeet, current month

Comment: Your expected output does not match the input. User `john` only has 2 donations this month... not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is wrong as you didn't filter out the september record in your results (only October 2013 should be taken into account).

Your expected output should be this:

```
| ID | USERNAME | AMOUNT | MONTHLY |
|----|----------|--------|---------|
|  1 |      rob |     20 |       1 |
|  2 |     john |     10 |       2 |
|  3 |     jane |      0 |       0 |
```

The query to get the output is:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.username,
  COALESCE(sum(d.amount), 0) amount,
  COUNT(d.uid) monthly
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN donations d
  ON u.id = d.uid
    AND (month(d.date), year(d.date)) = (month(CURDATE()), year(CURDATE()))
GROUP BY u.id
```

Assuming `users.ID` holds unique values you can leave the group by as `u.id` if it is not then you will have to group by `u.id, u.username`.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/909f3/1).

Comment: amazing! it works,is possible to add the sum of all donations? from all time?

Comment: My advice would be to solve that in a separate query. Right now you're grouping by username. If you add a new column with that information it would contain the same number repeated in all rows (not nice). Oh, you mean PER USER?

Comment: in current query we selected from current month right? is also possible to add the same but from all time

Comment: It is possible but that radically changes the question and the answer, and I have to leave now. I'd advise you to create a new question providing the expected output and someone out there will answer it :)

Comment: hi again, please help me again with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600003/sum-two-rows-and-order-by-date-total , I've added a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, sum(t2.amount) as amount, count(t2.amount,t2.`date`) as monthly
FROM users t1
inner join donations t2
  on t2.uid = t1.id
where month(t2.`date`)=month(curdate()) and year(t2.`date`)=year(curdate())
group by t1.username
```

Comment: If you group that way you assume that the `username` field functionally determines any other field in the `t1` table. Not advisable at all.

Answer (score 0):

How about this use current date and extract the month and match with the month from column `date`

### [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) , [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

```
SELECT t1.*, (CASE WHEN SUM(t2.amount) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(t2.amount) END) amount,
count(*) as monthly
FROM users t1
left join donations t2
  on t2.uid = t1.id
WHERE  MONTH(t2.`date`)=MONTH(CURDATE()) AND  YEAR(t2.`date`)=YEAR(CURDATE())
group by t1.id
```

Comment: @greenbandit see updated answer with left join and case condition

Comment: still getting only users who donated!